# Is there a way to stretch only a portion of the video?

Tags: premiere

I want to stretch the right hand 50% of the video only.  So that the left 50% of the video looks normal and the right 50% looks bizzarrely stretched.   Think of someones face smiling and laughing, where the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to work with two video tracks, use the crop and scale effect.

1. Create a sequence from your clip.
2. Apply the crop effect and set it to left: 50%
3. Locate the scale settings under the always present motion effect
4. Disable uniform scaling and set scale width to whatever you like
5. Add the clip again as a new track on top
6. Apply the crop effect on this track too and set it to right: 50%

And that's it.

Comment: Completely and utterly WORKED.  Thanks much